# kotlinc vs kotlinc-jvm to compile and kotlin vs java to run

Tags: kotlin, jvm, kotlinc

I have just installed `Kotlin` version `1.7.0` and the bin folder has the following runnables.

- `kotlinc`
- `kotlin-jvm`
- `kotlin`

After quick check found that `kotlinc` and `kotlin-jvm` are used to compile code to bytecode just like `javac` in Java. Why there are 2 commands for `kotlin` compilation. Is there any significant difference?

And, should I use `java` command to run the bytecode or `kotlin` command to run the bytecode. Any tradeoffs in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2):

The official [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/command-line.html) don't say too much about those command-line tools. And while you can call them with `-help`, that merely describes the other options they accept.

However, I can tell you what happens on my system (macOS, where Kotlin is installed using [HomeBrew](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/command-line.html#homebrew)). I don't know how much of the below applies to other platforms, but I suspect that at least Windows and Linux would be very similar.

Those executables are wrapper scripts, and so it's possible to see some of what they do. (They end up running Kotlin programs, which limits what you can see…)

Compiling:

`kotlinc-jvm` is a very simple wrapper script which merely calls `kotlinc` — so there's clearly no effective difference between them!

That shows Kotlin/JVM is the default compilation target, at least on my system. (`kotlinc-js` also calls `kotlinc`, but only after setting the `$KOTLIN_COMPILER` environment variable, which changes the program that `kotlinc` ends up running.) Maybe `kotlinc` has a different default on other systems — or at least they wanted to allow for the possibility.

Running:

AIUI, running `kotlin` is effectively equivalent to running `java`, except that `kotlin` adds the Kotlin runtime classes to the classpath.

You can of course add them manually when running `java` (e.g. in the `$CLASSPATH` or in a `-cp` parameter); but you would then need to know where they are, or have some way to find them. (On my system they're in `…/libexec/lib/`. The only essential one is the relevant `kotlin-stdlib` jar, though some code also needs `kotlin-reflect` and maybe others too. Or if you have a full Kotlin installation, I think you can simply add `kotlin-runner.jar`, which pulls in the others for you.)

I don't think there's any other benefit to using `kotlin`.

Note that if you build a [‘fat’ .jar](/questions/41794914/how-to-create-a-fat-jar-with-gradle-kotlin-script)/.war file, which includes the Kotlin runtime libs, then most systems will use `java` to run that anyway.